# Unit test with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have Web API project with the following service class called from API Controller. I want to write unit testcase for the below class using Moq framework. How can I construct multiple interfaces using Moq? If its not possible using Moq, is there any other framework?

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IInterface1 _interface1;
    private readonly IInterfaces2 _interface2;
    private readonly IInterface3 _interface3;

    public MyService(IInterface1 interface1,IInterface2 interface2,IInterface3 interface3)
    {
        _interface1=interface1;
        _interface2=interface2;            
        _interface3=interface3;
    }

    public SomeModel MyMethod1(1Model model)
    {
        //do something here.... 
    }

    public SomeMode2 MyMethod2(Model2 model)
    {
        //do something here.... 
    }

    public SomeMode3 MyMethod3(Model3 model)
    {
        //do something here.... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just construct a Mock of each dependency's interface and pass those in to your sut.

Comment: Mock the interfaces and pass them to the class under test. There is not much else shown to provide any additional help other than 
Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: You have to create the 3 mocks an inject it in the constructor, not much different from the toy example from most websites out there.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have these interfaces:

```
public interface IOne
{
    int Foo();
}

public interface ITwo
{
    int Foo(string str);
}
```

And you have a class which depends on above interfaces:

```
public class Some
{
    private readonly IOne one;
    private readonly ITwo two;

    public Some(IOne one, ITwo two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        // Uses one and two
    }
}
```

And now you want to test the `Work()` method and you want to mock the dependencies, here is how:

```
// Arrange
// Let's set up a mock for IOne so when Foo is called, it will return 5
var iOneMock = new Mock<IOne>();
iOneMock.Setup(x => x.Foo()).Returns(5);

// Let's set up the mock for ITwo when Foo is called with any string, 
// it will return 1
var iTwoMock = new Mock<ITwo>();
iTwoMock.Setup(x => x.Foo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);

var some = new Some(iOneMock.Object, iTwoMock.Object);

// Act
some.Work();

// Assert
// Let's verify iOneMock.Foo was called. 
iOneMock.Verify(x => x.Foo());
// Let's verify iTwoMock.Foo was called with string "One" and was called only once
iTwoMock.Verify(x => x.Foo("One"), Times.Once());
```

In my example above I tried to show methods which take an argument, methods which take no argument, verifying method was called and verify method was called once. That should give you and idea of the options available. There are many other options available. Please see the Moq documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoMoq](https://github.com/darrencauthon/AutoMoq) to solve the dependency injections.

```
var mocker = new AutoMoqer();
var myService = mocker.Create<MyService>();
var interface1 = mocker.GetMock<IInterface1>();
```